# detect folder path from uri

Tags: php, url-rewriting, path

Is there a reliable and easy way to detect the folder path in a url, disregarding url-rewritted rules?

Example of website hosted at folder `test` :

```
http://www.website.com/test/some/uri/rewritted
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Comment: Do you want to do this to local scripts or remote ones?

Comment: Actually, NO. Cos, your URL could be called from `/var/www/lib/foo/bar.php` or `/var/www/bar.php`, who knows..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever URL-rewriting the server does is designed so that it is invisible to outsiders. If you find out how to breach this, report the bug to the relevant web server inmeditely.